# Cannot run mongodb v3.0.3 on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: 32-bit, mongodb

(I know there are a lot of questions about this on `stackoverflow and this site` but no one fits my problem.).

I am a new recruit of mongodb. I am trying to install the v3.0.3 on my ubuntu 32 bit following their docs but cant get through it after issuing the install command. Googling a while, I learned that they do not prefer to use 32 bit but has a counterpart, to use the .tgz file I downloaded on their website for 32 bit.

I extracted the `mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.3.tgz` and place it to a folder on my desktop following their docs and the README inside the extracted folder.

When I issue the command `./mongod` inside bin directory to start mongod i got this message

```
2015-05-14T10:50:47.416+0800 I CONTROL  
2015-05-14T10:50:47.416+0800 W CONTROL  32-bit servers don't have    journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2015-05-14T10:50:47.416+0800 I CONTROL  
2015-05-14T10:50:47.477+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in  initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-05-14T10:50:47.477+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

This is my permission inside the extracted folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 repla replace  4096 May 13 14:06 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 replace replace  4096 May 13 14:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 replace replace  4096 May 13 14:06 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 replace replace 34520 May 13 14:06 GNU-AGPL-3.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 replace replace  1376 May 14 10:22 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 replace replace 22660 May 13 14:06 THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

How to fix this guys? I am a mysql user and I do not know a thing about this. I really want to try this out because I want to try MEAN.

Thanks in advance.

---

Seems theres no one online so my immediate fix on this is to install the v2.4 of mongodb..

I followed the answer in this question [How can I uninstall MongoDB and reinstall the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147135/how-can-i-uninstall-mongodb-and-reinstall-the-latest-version)

I just want to try mongodb to try `MEAN`.  If you have knowledge about my question, please post it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following is a viable workaround:

1. Create a folder `/data/db/` and provide proper write and read access
2. Start mongo db using `mongodb --journal`